# rails4でアイテムに付けられたスコアの合計値が大きい順のデータを取得するには？

Tags: rails-activerecord

UserはItemを複数所持していて
ItemはScoreを複数所持していて
Scoreにはvalueというintegerの値を持っているという構成のとき
１ユーザが所持しているItemsの中身をスコアの合計値が大きい順に並べ替えしたいです。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def mostScoreItems(start=0, length=65535)
    items
    .includes(:scores)
    .select('sum(value) as sum_value')
    .group('items.id')
    .order('sum_value desc')
    .references(:scores)
  end
end
```

前回の質問でなんとかここまででき、なんとか求めているデータを取得する事ができたのですが
いくつか実現したいことがあります。

① mostScoreItemsの第一引数startの値で、ソートを掛けた順のstartの値からデータを取得したい。

② mostScoreItemsの第二引数のlengthの値で、指定した件数だけデータを取得したい。

③ メソッドチェーンができなくなってるっぽいので、できるようにしたい。

恐らく、③を解決すれば、第一引数のstartは.offsetで繋ぎ、lengthは.limitで繋ぐことで、引数を渡す必要がなくなり、①と②も解決する上、コードの汎用性も高くなって幸せな気分になれると思ったのですが、Rails初心者のため、どうしてチェーンが切れてしまうのか、切れないようにするにはどのオブジェクトを返せばいいのか等、色々迷ってしまったため実現できませんでした。

そのため、引数をとるという方法で解決しようと思い.orderの後や.selectの後などに.limitや.offsetを付けてみたのですが駄目でした。

どうすれば解決できるか皆様の意見よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらくこんな感じでできると思います。

```
def most_score_items(offset = 0, limit = 65535)
  self
    .items
    .joins(:scores)
    .group("scores.item_id")
    .order("sum(scores.value) desc, items.id")
    .select("items.*, sum(scores.value) as sum_value")
    .offset(offset)
    .limit(limit)
end
```

合計値は、特異メソッド `sum_value` でアクセス出来ます。

```
res = User.most_score_items
# => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Item>, ...]
res.first.sum_value
# => 1234
```

SQL としては、

```
SELECT  items.*, sum(scores.value) as sum_value
FROM "items"
INNER JOIN "scores" ON "scores"."item_id" = "items"."id"
WHERE "items"."user_id" = ?
GROUP BY scores.item_id
ORDER BY sum(scores.value) desc, items.id
LIMIT ?
OFFSET ?
```

となります。

なお、標準SQLでは、`SELECT`句で作成した`sum_value`は`ORDER BY`句で利用できないため、`sum(scores.value)` と指定しています。(RDBMSによっては問題無く使えます。)

Comment: このメソッドをチェーンして.itemsにアクセスしてみたところ何故かScoreが更にhas_manyで所持しているオブジェクトの中身が空っぽになって‌​しまいました。

Comment: ここでは`SELECT`しかしていないので、別のところで何かしらの処理をしているのではありませんか? いずれにしても具体的な再現コードが無いと何とも言えません。

Comment: どうやらそのオブジェクトがpolymorphicでクラス名(？)を元にデータの結びつけを行っているため、SELECTでデータを抜き出した地点で結びつきが外れてしまうようです。毎度素早い対応していただいてとても感謝しています。もう少し調べてみます。

Comment: `.order("sum(scores.value) desc")`は`.order("sum(scores.value) desc, items.id")`にした方がよいです。ソート条件が同一のレコードがあった場合それらの並び順は一定になるとは限らないので、例えばOFFSET 0 LIMIT 10で取得したレコードとOFFSET 10で取得したレコードに同じレコードが含まれたり、逆にどちらにも含まれないレコードが発生する可能性があります。

Comment: @suzukis 本文の方を修正しておきました。ご指摘に感謝します。